# UnfinishedStubbingException received for JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, invocationtargetexception

Hi I am trying to test a method with Mockito and received the UnfinishedStubbingException. I am new to Mockito and not sure if I am doing something terrific :)

These are my stubs

```
 @InjectMocks
Constants constants;

@Mock
PreGeneratedAccountRepository preGeneratedAccountRepository;

@InjectMocks
PopulateUnqiueAccountNumber populateUnqiueAccountNumber;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

and my test method

```
 @Test
public void testCheckAvailableAccountNumbersForSuccess() throws Exception {

    populateUnqiueAccountNumber.setMinCount(2);
    populateUnqiueAccountNumber.setInsertRecordCount(2);

    long preGeneratedRowCount = 1;
    long preGeneratedAccountCount = 0;
    long accountNum = 8609024563l; 

    PreGeneratedAccount preGeneratedAccount = new PreGeneratedAccount();

    when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {              
            return preGeneratedRowCount;
        }
    });
    when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAccountNum(accountNum)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {              
            return preGeneratedAccountCount;
        }
    });
    when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(preGeneratedAccount));

    // call testing method
    populateUnqiueAccountNumber.checkAvailableAccountNumbers();

    // Verify the mock calls
    verify(preGeneratedAccountRepository, times(1)).countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE);
    verify(preGeneratedAccountRepository, times(1)).countByAccountNum(accountNum);
    verify(preGeneratedAccountRepository, times(1)).saveAndFlush(preGeneratedAccount);

}
```

and my service method

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "${app.config.cron.rate}")
public void checkAvailableAccountNumbers() {
    LOGGER.debug("Method execution started :: " + new Date());

    try {
        long rowCount = preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE);
        LOGGER.debug("Available account numbers in Database" + rowCount);

        int totalRecordInserted = 0;

        if (rowCount < minCount) {
            do {
                int count = insertRecordCount - totalRecordInserted;
                LOGGER.debug("Number of Record need to insert::" + count);
                int recordInserted = insertAccountNumbers(count);
                totalRecordInserted = totalRecordInserted + recordInserted;
                LOGGER.debug("totalRecordInserted::" + totalRecordInserted);
            } while (totalRecordInserted < insertRecordCount);
        }
    }

    catch (DataAccessException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An exception was encountered when inserting account numbers", e);
        throw e;
    }
    LOGGER.debug("Method execution ended :: " + new Date());
}
```

I am receiving error at this line in my service

```
preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE);
```

Exception

```
    Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.cardinalhealth.chh.batch.PopulateUnqiueAccountNumberTest.testCheckAvailableAccountNumbersForSuccess(PopulateUnqiueAccountNumberTest.java:80)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line.

```
when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(preGeneratedAccount));
```

You haven't specified what you want Mockito to do when this method is called.

Note also that you've used `Answer` twice when you don't need to.  You can just use `thenReturn` each time you've used an `Answer`, for example,

```
when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE)).thenReturn(pregeneratedAccountCount);
```

Comment: Also, I don't understand the need of `@InjectMocks` on the `Constants` here.

Comment: But when I debug it is breaking at this line preGeneratedAccountRepository.countByAcctNumAvailableFlag(Constants.FALSE); in my service. FYI, first I tried the way you mentioned for return but getting the same error. SO I changed to Answer to see if it fix the problem but no luck @DavidWallace

Comment: If it breaks for when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(preGeneratedAccount)); this then it has to break while I am in my test method while debugging but it doesn't. It passed the step there and my control goes to service class method and failed there

Comment: Yes.  That's what happens with unfinished stubbing.  Mockito is still waiting to find out what you want to have happen on a call to `saveAndFlush`.  Mockito can't know that you've failed to stub correctly until you start running your test, and call a method on a mock.

Comment: Forget the second half of my answer for now - first, just fix the line I told you to fix.  Supply a `thenReturn` or `thenAnswer` for `when(preGeneratedAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(preGeneratedAccount))`.  That's what's causing your problem.

Comment: That's solved the problem. Now I understand the exception and the behavior of Mockito for this exception. Thanks @DavidWallace